# Finding points that are closest and most far way from origin - using calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, lagrange-multiplier

As the title says i want to find $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}$ that are connected with thse two "equations":
$$z^2-x^2-y^2=0$$
$$x-2z-3=0$$
And are the closest or most far away from origin $(0,0,0)$
So i know i need to use Lagrange multipliers and than find maximums and minimums with a system, but i get lost at trying to get that.
Normally i had a function and then some "sub"functions but now i don't have a main function or i just don't notice how to solve it using calculus.
I think it's solved with Lagrange multiplier, if not i am ope for suggestions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The "main" function is the one you want to minimize, so in this case, it is the distance from the origin.

Comment: @5xum yeah thank you, it was in the answer down below as well, so it's undestandable now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first remark, if I may : minimizing the distance is the same as minimizing the square of the distance.

So, you want to minimize $$f=x^2+y^2+z^2$$ subject to the constraints $$z^2-x^2-y^2=0\qquad , \qquad x-2z-3=0$$ So, let us define $$F=x^2+y^2+z^2+\lambda(z^2-x^2-y^2)+\mu(x-2z-3)$$ and work as usual. $$F'_x=2x -2 \lambda  x+\mu$$ $$F'_y=2 y-2 \lambda  y$$ $$F'_z=2z+2 \lambda  z-2 \mu $$ $$F'_\lambda=z^2-x^2-y^2$$ $$F'_\mu=x-2z-3$$ At the extremum, all the derivatives must be $0$.

I am sure that you can take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

When we face such problems, the first reaction (you properly had) is to think about Lagrange multipliers.

However, in some case such as this one, the problem can be extremely simplified.

We want to minimize $$f=x^2+y^2+z^2\tag 1$$subject to the constraints $$z^2-x^2-y^2=0\tag 2$$ $$x-2z-3=0\tag 3$$ The first constraint can rewrite $$z^2=x^2+y^2\implies f=2(x^2+y^2)\tag 4$$ and the second constraint gives $z=\frac{x-3}{2}$. So $$z^2=x^2+y^2\implies \frac{1}{4} (x-3)^2=x^2+y^2\implies y^2=-\frac{3 x^2}{4}-\frac{3 x}{2}+\frac{9}{4}\tag 5$$ and since $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}$, $$y^2 \geq 0 \implies -3\leq x\leq 1\tag 6$$ So, finally, we look for the extrema of the function $$f=\frac{1}{2} (x-3)^2$$ in the above range.

Simpler, isn't it ?

Comment: yeah, that is much simpler,didn't even see it

Comment: @MathIsTheWayOfLife. I made both answers on purpose. The first one to show how to solve it using Lagrange multipliers. In fact, from the very beginning, I noticed what I gave in the second answer. One possible conclusion : before starting solving the problem, have a deep look at what is given. Please notice that if one of the equality constraints is linear with respect to one variable, you can eliminate the variable and the constraint. Cheers :-)